# Using Oracle pre-built Docker image as a service for GitLab CI runner

Tags: oracle, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am currently in the process of creating an integration-tests pipeline for a few project we have running around that require the presence of an Oracle database to work. In order to do so, I have gone through the process of creating a dockerized pre-built Oracle database using the instruction mentioned in this document.

https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/samples/prebuiltdb

I have successfully built the image and I'm able to verify that it works indeed correctly. I have pushed the image in question to one of our custom docker repositories and I am also able to successfully fetch from the context of the runner.

My main problem is that when the application attempts to connect to the database it fails with a connection refused error as if the database is not running (mind you I'm running the runner locally in order to test this). My question are the following:

1. When using a custom image, what is the name the runner exposes it?
   For example, the documentation states that when I use `mysql:latest`
   then the exposed service name would be `mysql`. Is this the case for
   custom images as well? Should I name it with an alias?
2. Do I need to expose ports/brigde docker networks in order to get
   this to work correctly? My reasoning behind the failure leads me to
   believe that the image that runs the application is not able to
   properly communicate with the Oracle service.

For reference my `gitlab-ci.yml` for the job in question is the following:

```
integration_test:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - echo 127.0.0.1 inttests.myapp.com >> /etc/hosts
  services:
    - <repository>/devops/fts-ora-inttests-db:latest
  script:
    - ./gradlew -x:test integration-test:test
  cache:
    key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
    paths:
      - build
      - .gradle
  only:
    - master
    - develop
    - merge_requests
    - tags
  except:
    - api
```

Can anyone please lend a hand in getting this to work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I recently configured a `gitlab-ci.yml` to use an Oracle docker image as a `service` and used our custom docker repository to fetch the image.

I'll answer your question one by one below:

---

*1.a When using a custom image, what is the name the runner exposes it? For example, the documentation states that when I use mysql:latest then the exposed service name would be mysql. Is this the case for custom images as well?*

By default, the Gitlab runner will deduce the name of the service based from the following convention [1]:

> The default aliases for the service’s hostname are created from its image name following these rules:
>
> 1. Everything after the colon (:) is stripped.
> 2. Slash (/) is replaced with double underscores (__) and the primary alias is created.
> 3. Slash (/) is replaced with a single dash (-) and the secondary alias is created (requires GitLab Runner v1.1.0 or higher).

So in your case, since the service name you used is `<repository>/devops/fts-ora-inttests-db:latest`, the Gitlab runner will by default generate **two (2)** aliases.

1. `<repository>__devops__fts-ora_inttests-db`
2. `<repository>-devops-fts-ora-inttests-db`

In order to connect to your **oracle database service**, you need to refer to the alias in your configuration file or source code.

e.g.

```
database.url=jdbc:oracle:thin@<repository>__devops__fts-ora_inttests-db:1521:xe
//OR
database.url=jdbc:oracle:thin@<repository>-devops-fts-ora-inttests-db:1521:xe
```

*1.b Should I name it with an alias?*

In my opinion, you should just declare an alias for the service in order to keep the alias name simple which the runner will automatically use and you can refer it to it the same way.

e.g.

```
// .gitlab-ci.yml
services:
   - name: <repository>/devops/fts-ora-inttests-db:latest
     alias: oracle-db

// my-app.properties
database.url=jdbc:oracle:thin@oracle-db:1521:xe
```

---

*2. Do I need to expose ports/bridge docker networks in order to get this to work correctly?*

Yes, the Oracle DB docker image that would be used for the service must have ports `1521` and `5500` exposed declared in the **dockerfile** in order for you to access it.

---

Sources:

1. [Gitlab Documentation Accessing the Services](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#accessing-the-services)

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Melvin Sy.
I've a follow up question as I'm unable to connect to oracle service. I see the below error, when the script is trying to run sql command. Do you know what the issue might be? Thanks


    `Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
    ORA-12526, TNS:listener: all appropriate instances are in restricted mode`